# ActionScript 3.0 работа с XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Всем привет, прошу помощи.
Во **Flash Builder 4.5** пытаюсь подключиться к XML файлу, но что-то не срабатывает.

Ниже код(точнее, кусок кода до ошибки):

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.net.URLLoader;
        import flash.xml;
        
        var myXML: XML = new XML(); 
        var XML_URL: String = "C:\req.xml"; 
        var myXMLURL: URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 
        var myLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL); 
        
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
```

и вот на последней строчке среда выдаёт ошибку:

> Это строка содержит несколько выделений:
>
> -1120: Обращение несуществующего свойства myLoader.
>
> -1120: Обращение несуществующего свойства xmlLoaded.

Я в AS 3 новичок и никак не могу понять, в чём моя ошибка. Помогите, кто может, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Насчет `Flash Builder 4.5` не уверен, но в `ADOBE FLASH ACTIONSCRIPT 3` это выглядит вот так.

События должны быть подключены полностью во `FLASH`, это выглядит так:

```
import fL.events.*;
```

В Вашем случае это так:

```
import Flash.events.*;

var xml:XML = new XML();
var xmlList:XMLList =new XMLList();

 var xmlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('messages.xml');
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE,xmlLoaded);
    loader.load(xmlRequest);
```

У Вас отсутствует эта функция:

```
function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void 
{
xml=XML(e.target.data);
xmlList = xml.children();
)
```

Да, и еще в `ACTIONSCRIPT 3` путь `"C:\req.xml"` может вызвать ошибку, так как в строке есть обратный слеш, его необходимо экранировать - "C:\req.xml".

Comment: Функция xmlLoaded объявлена ниже в том коде. Я там, правда, объект XML читаю по итемам. немного изменив ваш код под себя(имена переменных), я получаю те же ошибки. При этом даже не в одной строке, как у меня, а в двух: loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlLoaded) и loader.load(xmlRequest); 
везде одна и та же ошибка - 1120 Обращение несуществующего свойства

Comment: Вот полностью код который работает
var xml:XML = new XML();
var xmlList:XMLList =new XMLList();
loadXml();
function loadXml(e:MouseEvent=null):void {
 var xmlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest('C:\\list.xml');
 var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlLoaded);
 loader.load(xmlRequest);
}
function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void {
 xml=XML(e.target.data);
 xmlList=xml.children();
это просто вывод в текстовое поле для проверки
 text_aww.text=xmlList[0].name;
 
}

Comment: по поводу ошибок есть предположение что это связано с обращением к xml. здесь xml выглядет так 

<list>
<list>
<name>
проверка чтения
</name>
 </list>
</list>
 если в этой строке заменить число 0 на 1  xmlList[0].name
то произойдёт ошибка так как дочерний элемент <list> здесь только один. незабудте что в строке  xmlList=xml.children(); мы перешли в дочерний тег <list>

Comment: Странно, на третьей строке (loadXml();) возникает ошибка 1180 Вызов предположительно неопределенного метода loadXml.

Comment: loadXml(); это функция которую мы описали ниже я удивлён почему такая ошибка компилято в actionscript3 должен находить все функции на страници а их вызов может осущиствлятся до объявления самой функции. ну рас ошибка значит переместите вызов функций после их объявления. тоесть вотак:

Comment: var xml:XML = new XML();
var xmlList:XMLList =new XMLList();




function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void {
xml=XML(e.target.data);
xmlList=xml.children();
text_aww.text=xmlList[0].name;

}





function loadXml(e:MouseEvent=null):void {
var xmlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest('C:\\list.xml');
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlLoaded);
loader.load(xmlRequest);
}

loadXml();